# Can't connect to Daemon Deluge on CentOS 6.10

Tags: shell, centos, daemon, deluge

I want to connect to the Deluge daemon from the webui but it simply doesn't work.

My install script of deluge

```
#!/bin/bash
rpm --import http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/RPM-GPG-KEY-nux.ro
yum -y install epel-release && rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el6/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-2.el6.nux.noarch.rpm
yum install deluge -y
/etc/init.d/deluge-daemon start
```

Here is the request to connect :

[image]

The response I get :

[image]

I checked if everything is running with `ps aux | grep deluge`

[image]

I'm running it on CentOS 6.10

**core.conf**

```
{
  "file": 1,
  "format": 1
}{
  "info_sent": 0.0,
  "lsd": true,
  "max_download_speed": -1.0,
  "send_info": false,
  "natpmp": true,
  "move_completed_path": "/home/mat5",
  "peer_tos": "0x00",
  "enc_in_policy": 1,
  "queue_new_to_top": false,
  "ignore_limits_on_local_network": true,
  "rate_limit_ip_overhead": true,
  "daemon_port": 8159,
  "torrentfiles_location": "/home/mat5",
  "max_active_limit": 8,
  "geoip_db_location": "/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat",
  "upnp": true,
  "utpex": true,
  "max_active_downloading": 3,
  "max_active_seeding": 5,
  "allow_remote": true,
  "outgoing_ports": [
    0,
    0
  ],
  "enabled_plugins": [],
  "max_half_open_connections": 50,
  "download_location": "/home/mat5",
  "compact_allocation": false,
  "max_upload_speed": -1.0,
  "plugins_location": "/home/mat5/.config/deluge/plugins",
  "max_connections_global": 200,
  "enc_prefer_rc4": true,
  "cache_expiry": 60,
  "dht": true,
  "stop_seed_at_ratio": false,
  "stop_seed_ratio": 2.0,
  "max_download_speed_per_torrent": -1,
  "prioritize_first_last_pieces": false,
  "max_upload_speed_per_torrent": -1,
  "auto_managed": true,
  "enc_level": 2,
  "copy_torrent_file": false,
  "max_connections_per_second": 20,
  "listen_ports": [
    6881,
    6891
  ],
  "max_connections_per_torrent": -1,
  "del_copy_torrent_file": false,
  "move_completed": false,
  "autoadd_enable": false,
  "proxies": {
    "peer": {
      "username": "",
      "password": "",
      "hostname": "",
      "type": 0,
      "port": 8080
    },
    "web_seed": {
      "username": "",
      "password": "",
      "hostname": "",
      "type": 0,
      "port": 8080
    },
    "tracker": {
      "username": "",
      "password": "",
      "hostname": "",
      "type": 0,
      "port": 8080
    },
    "dht": {
      "username": "",
      "password": "",
      "hostname": "",
      "type": 0,
      "port": 8080
    }
  },
  "dont_count_slow_torrents": false,
  "add_paused": false,
  "random_outgoing_ports": true,
  "max_upload_slots_per_torrent": -1,
  "new_release_check": true,
  "enc_out_policy": 1,
  "seed_time_ratio_limit": 7.0,
  "remove_seed_at_ratio": false,
  "autoadd_location": "/home/mat5",
  "max_upload_slots_global": 4,
  "seed_time_limit": 180,
  "cache_size": 512,
  "share_ratio_limit": 2.0,
  "random_port": true,
  "listen_interface": ""
}
```

**web.conf**

```
{
  "file": 1,
  "format": 1
}{
  "port": 8158,
  "enabled_plugins": [],
  "pwd_sha1": "d3cce2b30bb5d399ae9be6beddb77c0b1c4p9592",
  "theme": "gray",
  "show_sidebar": true,
  "sidebar_show_zero": false,
  "pkey": "ssl/daemon.pkey",
  "https": false,
  "sessions": {
    "8e81ab960021n960f816ea338f437d61": {
      "login": "admin",
      "expires": 1545299166.0,
      "level": 10
    }
  },
  "base": "/",
  "pwd_salt": "065e6352c19536326d24c361m1448535e7046a7d",
  "show_session_speed": false,
  "first_login": false,
  "cert": "ssl/daemon.cert",
  "session_timeout": 3600,
  "default_daemon": 8159,
  "sidebar_multiple_filters": true
}
```

I tested the same config on CentOS 7 and it's working very well. I also tried to connect to the Daemon throught the deluge console but there is no daemon online.

I found a similar issue on the official forum : https://forum.deluge-torrent.org/viewtopic.php?t=49589. I'm wondering if it's beacause I'm using the version 2.6 of Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use an older version of Deluge. The last version supported by CentOS 6.10 is `deluge-1.3.10-1`.

Here is the updated install script of Deluge :

```
#!/bin/bash
rpm --import http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/RPM-GPG-KEY-nux.ro
yum -y install epel-release && rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el6/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-2.el6.nux.noarch.rpm
yum install deluge-1.3.10-1.el6.nux -y
yum install python-requests -y
```